# Вывод числа без сноса разрядов

Tags: php

Простенький, я думаю, вопрос. Как можно вывести число без сноса разрядов.
Выводит 1.82E-8, а мне требуется число без сноса 0.0000000182.

Answer (score 1):

```
$n = 0.0000000182;
echo rtrim(sprintf('%.15f', $n), '0');
```

[sprint](http://php.net/sprintf) форматирует вывод числа (в данном случае 15 знаков после запятой), [rtrim](http://php.net/rtrim) удаляет нули с конца на случай, если выводимое число короче.